# In bootstrap, how to make one div takes full width when possible

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, we can place two divs next to each other using the following technique

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">first div</div>
   <div class="col-md-12">second div</div>
</div>
```

But, if I hide the first div by javascript or display:none, I would like the second div to take all the 24 spaces.

Is there a way to easily achieve that without changing its class to col-md-24 in javscript when hiding the first div?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not.  But as you mentioned already, it's as simple as:

```
$('.col-md-12').eq(0).addClass('hidden');
$('.col-md-12').eq(1).removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-24');
```

Obviously this is just in reference to your example above, as you'd be better of using a real CSS class and not eq's.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3, the full width of any container is 12 and there is no `".col-md-24"` class.

If you have two div

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">first div</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">second div</div>
</div>
```

You can hide first div and modify the second div's class to col-md-12.

Comment: Or you can delete class if the element is block